# How do i gain access to the Auroran Mines?

Tags: fable-3

Can someone help me?

I have tried everything and i can't find the Auroran Mines in Fable 3.  I've looked all over the internet but I'm not finding the answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Fable Wiki:](http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/Auroran_Mine):

> The Auroran Mine is an area which you only gain access to by choosing to betray the promise made to Kalin during Blindness. The decision is made after becoming King or Queen during the quest Weight of the World.

So if you didn't betray the promise, you can't access it.

Comment: As a sidenote, this took all of five seconds to find.  There's no way the asker has looked all over the internet.

Comment: I did break the promise i just can't find it.

Comment: do you know where it is

Comment: You asked how to access it. Not where it is.

Comment: sorry well i was just asking if YOU knew

Comment: i found it i think